# Symfony2 Translations with XLIFF / XLF Best Practices

Tags: symfony, translation, xliff

I have started using the translation system in Symfony2.

All works very well.

However I have one question about best practice when it comes to referencing the source / target string from a twig view file.

Given this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="1">
            <source>Short String</source>
            <target>Short String</target>
        </trans-unit>

        <trans-unit id="2">
            <source>Some really long string for example a paragraph about some random thing that is likely to change in the future</source>
            <target>Some really long string for example a paragraph about some random thing that is likely to change in the future</target>
        </trans-unit>       

    </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

No problems using like:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'messages' %}

<h3>{{ 'Multicoin Cryptocurrency Online Wallet' | trans }}</h3>

<p>{{ 'Some really long string for example a paragraph about some random thing that is likely to change in the future' | trans }}</p>
```

I know you can in the source section use short source references like:

```
<trans-unit id="2">
            <source>page.long.paragraph</source>
            <target>Some really long string for example a paragraph about some random thing that is likely to change in the future</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Which makes the twig part much cleaner:

```
{% trans_default_domain 'messages' %}

<h3>{{ 'Multicoin Cryptocurrency Online Wallet' | trans }}</h3>

<p>{{ 'page.long.paragraph' | trans }}</p>
```

The question is if I want to give the original en translation file to a translator to translate into another language it would be far better to have the whole string that needs to be translated in the  field. However that makes the twig code rather untidy. Is there another way to reference the translations string in twig without having to use the whole source string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you only have 2 options: Real messages or keyword messages.

And yes, keyword messages doesn't work that easy if you are adding a new language. And Xliff doesn't have a good support for it. That's the reason why you see the real messages being used when using Xliff files.

Comment: Thanks - I have resorted to adding the real source string in a <!-- Comment --> where the source is unreasonably long and use keywords in the <source>.

Comment: I recommend to use one type of messages only, so use keyword messages everywhere (that means for both long and short strings)

Comment: Can't believe Symfony is abusing XLF files in such a idiotic way.

Why don't they use it instead in the way it's meant to be used? Check if the ID exists in source files and find the corresponding ID in the translated files? This completely destroys the benefit of XLF files for translators and if we use the other way we end up with Translations in 100 places (Controllers, Twig etc) or we create a third language for "developers"

Do you know if there are any requests to change this behavior?